# How can i improve my accuracy of audio data classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I need to classify if a sound is of a hammer or not.
The dataset contains 8000 .wav audio files(approx 1s each) for training and about 2000 for testing with 2 classes for classification(0 if the sound is not of a hammer or 1 if it is). I tried extracting features(mfcc and padding) and to build my network, but when I fit the model with the extracted data I cannot get over 70.5% accuracy.

What can I change or what else can I consider that would increase my accuracy? Also if my approach is flawed please tell me.

Here is the data extraction part:

```
def get_traing_features(row):
    file_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path_train), str(row[0]))
    audio_train, sfreq_train = lb.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
    mfcc = lb.feature.mfcc(y=audio_train, sr=sfreq_train, n_mfcc=40)
    pad_width = max_pad_len - mfcc.shape[1]
    mfccs = np.pad(mfcc, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)), mode='constant')

    feature = mfccs
    label = row[1]
    return pd.Series([feature, label])

def get_validation(row):
    file_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path_validation), str(row[0]))
    audio_val, sfreq_val = lb.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
    mfcc = lb.feature.mfcc(y=audio_val, sr=sfreq_val, n_mfcc=40)
    pad_width = max_pad_len - mfcc.shape[1]
    mfccs = np.pad(mfcc, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)), mode='constant')

    feature = mfccs
    label = row[1]
    return pd.Series([feature, label])

train_data= train_data.apply(parser, axis=1)
train_data.columns = ['feature', 'label']x = np.array(temp.feature.tolist())
x = np.array(train_data.feature.tolist())
y = np.array(train_data.label.tolist())
y_binary = to_categorical(y)
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], numb_rows, numb_cols, num_channels)

test_data = validation.apply(get_validation, axis=1)
test_data.columns = ['feature', 'label']
x_val = np.array(temp_val.feature.tolist())
y_val = np.array(temp_val.label.tolist())
y_binary_val = to_categorical(y_val)
x_val = x_val.reshape(x_val.shape[0], numb_rows, numb_cols, num_channels)
```

And here is the CNN:

```
numb_rows = 40
numb_cols = 174
num_channels = 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(numb_rows, numb_cols, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='./saved_models/weights.best.basic_cnn.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

model.fit(x, y_binary, batch_size=10, epochs=200, callbacks=[checkpointer], verbose=1)

y_pred = model.predict_classes(x_val)

acc = accuracy_score(y_val, y_pred)
```

Comment: Are you possibly in a class imbalance setting? How many of your 8K training samples are of class 'hammer'?

Comment: 4076 are hammers so it almost 50% - 50%

Comment: Difficult to say more. Start by removing all dropout (it should not be used by default, only if you have signs of overfitting) and the `GlobalAveragePooling2D` layer before the last one.

Comment: I tried removing the dropouts, but only got a 0.09% increase. Deleting GlobalAveragePooling2D gives me the following error: "Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (8000, 2)"

Comment: Fixed it by replacing with model.add(Flatten()) but it lowers my accuracy